# probability(french card)

Tags: probability

From a standard 52-card deck of French playing cards, two random cards are missing(we don't know which ones). We pick 4 cards(without replacement). 'A' is such an event, where we pick exactly 3 aces.
P(A)=?

Comment: Are you able to solve now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll need to define a few events of the cards missing in order to approach this problem.

Let's define the three possible events of the cards missing first:

1. $0$ aces may be missing. Let's call this event $X$.
2. $1$ ace may be missing. Let's call this event $Y$.
3. $2$ aces may be missing. Let's call this event $Z$.

Note the importance of defining the above events in the context of our problem.

Now let's jump into the calculations:

Note the following:

$$P(A) = P(A \cap X) + P(A \cap Y) + P(A\cap Z)$$

Now use the fact that

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)\times P(B)$$

Leaving out the details for you to work em out.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Vizag!  

P(A∩Z)=0
P(A∩Y)=3C3*47C1
P(A∩X)=4C3*46C1
I am not sure whether these are correct. The result should be 0.000738, but I get a different result.
What do you think?
Thank you

Comment: You forgot two things in the above comment. 1.) You forgot to multiply by the $P(Y)$, $P(X)$ in the last two expressions respectively. Read the answer again and note that $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)\times P(B)$. So for example $P(A \cap Y) = P(A|Y)*P(Y)$ where $P(Y) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\times \binom {48}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}$. And 2.) I think you forgot to add the denominator in the comment above. Make these corrections and repost a comment and I'll check whether they are right.

Comment: Were you able to solve?

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right, I forgot the denominators in the rush.
My new solution is:
(∩)=(|)∗() = ((3C3*47C1)/(50C2))  *  (4C1*48C1)/(52C2)
(∩X)=(|X)∗(X) = ((4C3*46C1)/(50C2))  *  (4C0*48C2)/(52C2)
(∩Z)=0
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Now it looks correct! If you have no other queries, plz mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: Thank you, you are great!